# How to delete duplicated characters in a string?

Tags: java, if-statement, merge, switch-statement

Okay, I'm a huge newbie in the world of java and I can't seem to get this program right. I am suppose to delete the duplicated characters in a 2 worded string and printing the non duplicated characters.
for example:I input the words "computer program." the output should be "cute" because these are the only char's that are not repeated.

I made it until here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Input two words: "); 
    String str1 = Keyboard.readString();
    String words[] = str1.split(" "); 
    String str2 = words[0] + "  "; 
    String str3 = words[words.length - 1] ;
}
```

but i don't know how to output the  characters. Could someone help me?
I don't know if I should use if, switch, for, do, or do-while...... I'm confused.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be "cute ga"?

Comment: Look into using a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Map the character to their counts with one pass of the string. Then iterate over the entries of the map and append characters of frequency 1 to some buffer (i.e. `StringBuilder`). Finally, print the result.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to build up logic for your problem. First break the problem statement and start finding solution for that. Here you go for steps,

1. Read every character from a string.
2. Add it to a collection, but before adding that, just check whether it exists.
3. If it exists just remove it and continue the reading of characteer.
4. Once you are done with reading the characters, just print the contents of collection to console using System.out.println.

I will recommend you to refer books like "Think like A Programmer". This will help you to get started with logic building.

Comment: Can you please select appropriate post and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint: use a hash map (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Adding following code after last line of your main program will resolve your issue.

```
    char[] strChars = str2.toCharArray();
    String newStr="";
    for (char c : strChars) {
        String charStr = ""+c;
        if(!str3.contains(charStr.toLowerCase()) && !str3.contains(charStr.toUpperCase())){
            newStr+=c;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(newStr);
```

This code loops through all the characters of the first word and check if the second string contains that character (In any form of case Lower or Upper). If it is not containing, adding it to output string and at the end printing it.

Hope this will work in your case.

Comment: thankyou. I was fixing the program when I saw your result. I had a problem with the if statement. This completed the program. very greatful.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it in just 1 line?

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "");
```